# Command Line browser autofill

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, command-line, autofill

I have to authenticate multiple users through a network everyday through a very simplistic webpage, which only consists of two text-boxes.

My Question is whether there is any way to call a command through windows command prompt to auto-fill these boxes using html tags or any other scripting language recommendations to automate this activity.

I use mostly chrome or internet explorer but am open to any browser with this kind of support.

Basic Idea of what I had in mind

```
iexplore "url" "id="textbox1" username" "id="textbox2" password"
chrome "url" 'id="textbox1" username" "id="textbox2" password"
```

Comment: ended up using curl and a little magic

Answer (score 1):

Selenium/WebDriver can do this. You'll need to write a little code and install WebDriver, so it may be a little more heavyweight than you want.  The SeleniumIDE plugin for FireFox might let you automate this, as well.